# How to create IDs for nested ul and li tags in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a requirement to build a menu tree with id in the following pattern.
The data to the tree is fed from database which returns a dataset with multiple data tables.
Can anyone help how to do this using string builder?
Following is an example how the items should be arranged;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
<div id="tree" class="tree" valign="left" runat="server">
 <ul id='ctlTreeView_1'>
   <li id='ctlTreeView_1_1'><label title="someUrl" ondblclick='javascript:dblClick(this)'>Label list</label>
    <ul id='ctlTreeView_1_1_1'>
       <li id='ctlTreeView_1_1_1_1'><label title="label1" ondblclick='javascript:dblClick(this)'>Label1</label></li>
       <li id='ctlTreeView_1_1_1_2'><label title="label2" ondblclick='javascript:dblClick(this)'>Label2</label></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would use `StringBuilder` in combination with `string.Format`, to use placeholder for placing the id's in the html-code.

Just create a string builder:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder()
```

and append all lines:

```
builder.AppendLine("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
// ...    
builder.AppendLine("</html>");
```

If you want to place some id's in a tag, just use:

```
builder.AppendLine(string.Format("<ul id='{0}'>", "YOUR_ID"));
// ....
builder.AppendLine("</ul>");
```

You can put those lines in a loop, if you want to iterate over your db-result.

Later you can simple use `.ToString()` to get the complete html-code:

```
string htmlCode = builder.ToString();
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Since you are using asp.net you can also use asp.net `classes` to build html controls. Just take a look at [HtmlGenericControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=VS.90).aspx). Maybe this is also an option.

Comment: @BendRg, So far I'm able to build the list under html as per your suggestion. But while generating the IDs for ul and li tags in the above mentioned pattern, I'm bit stuck.

Comment: So the id value is your problem, not the code generation?

Comment: Initially I had problem with the both generating list and ID creation.Now I'm able to generate the list. Could you please suggest on ID generation from code behind..Thanks

Comment: That depends on how you want to generate the ids. Do they have a specific content, where do you want to reference on them, or reuse them? That's some thing we currently don't know. If you don't need any id later, just do not use any id.

Comment: The IDs should be generated exactly in the same pattern shown in the html list. These IDs will be required while searching/looping through the nodes uniquely.

Comment: @BendRg, Any help or suggestion on generating the ID pattern..?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `StringBuilder`, it would be better to declare the root `ul` control with the `runat="server"` tag, and populate it from codebehind with children controls, like in this example:

.aspx file:

```
  <ul id="ctlTreeView_1" runat="server" />
```

.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var li_1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li") {
        InnerText = "first item",
        ID = "li_1"
    };
    ctlTreeView_1.Controls.Add(li_1);

    var ul_2 = new HtmlGenericControl("ul") {
        ID = "ul_2"
    };
    li_1.Controls.Add(ul_2);

    var li_2_1 = new HtmlGenericControl("li") {
        InnerText = "first inner item",
        ID = "li_2_1"
    };
    ul_2.Controls.Add(li_2_1);

}
```